# react native new android activity destroys MainActivity

Tags: android, react-native, braintree

I'm trying in integrate Braintree Paypal into react native for Android.

I'm using the android example from here https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/paypal/checkout-with-paypal/android/v4/

i can launch the activity from react native like this

```
@ReactMethod
  public void paypalPaymentRequest(ReadableMap options, Promise promise) {
    String clientToken = options.getString("clientToken");
    Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();

      Intent intent = new Intent(currentActivity, PayPalActivity.class);
//      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
//      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
      intent.putExtra("clientToken", clientToken); 
      currentActivity.startActivity(intent);
    
  }
```

The paypal browser does open when i call the paypalPaymentRequest function however it destroys the Main Application activity with this error

> win=Window{b01221 u0
> com.reactnativebraintreepaymentsexample/com.braintree.reactnativepayments.activity.PayPalActivity}
> destroySurfaces: appStopped=true win.mWindowRemovalAllowed=false
> win.mRemoveOnExit=false win.mViewVisibility=8
> caller=com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5841
> com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.destroySurfaces:5822
> com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.notifyAppStopped:5886
> com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord.activityStopped:6512
> com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.activityStopped:253
> android.app.IActivityClientController$Stub.onTransact:596
> com.android.server.wm.ActivityClientController.onTransact:129

I have tried to adjust with indent flags but cant seem to resolve the error.

I've declared the browser switch activity in the android manifest.xml like this

```
<activity android:name=".activity.PayPalActivity"
      android:exported="true">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="${applicationId}.braintree" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

My PayPalActivity class

```
public class PayPalActivity extends ReactActivity implements PayPalListener {

  private BraintreeClient braintreeClient;
  private PayPalClient payPalClient;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String clientToken = getIntent().getStringExtra("clientToken");
    braintreeClient = new BraintreeClient(this, clientToken);
    payPalClient = new PayPalClient(this, braintreeClient);
    payPalClient.setListener(this);
    this.myTokenizePayPalAccountWithCheckoutMethod();
    // ... rest of your code ...
  }

  private void myTokenizePayPalAccountWithCheckoutMethod() {
    PayPalCheckoutRequest request = new PayPalCheckoutRequest("1.00");
    request.setCurrencyCode("USD");
    request.setIntent(PayPalPaymentIntent.AUTHORIZE);

    payPalClient.tokenizePayPalAccount(this, request);
  }

  private void myTokenizePayPalAccountWithVaultMethod() {
    PayPalVaultRequest request = new PayPalVaultRequest();
    request.setBillingAgreementDescription("Your agreement description");

    payPalClient.tokenizePayPalAccount(this, request);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPayPalSuccess(@NonNull PayPalAccountNonce payPalAccountNonce) {
    // send nonce to server
  }

  @Override
  public void onPayPalFailure(@NonNull Exception error) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

How do i stop the new activity destroying the main app?

Comment: Starting a new activity can always kill the ones that were previously on the stack.  That's the nature of Android.  That's why you're supposed to save your state in onSaveInstanceState, which will get called when that happens.  Then restore it in onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: Although I'm not sure that's what your log there is showing.  It's showing the UI being removed, not necessarily a call to onStop of the Activity.